# ASP.NET MVC 3 Redirect/route URL back to subdomain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-routing, url-routing

I have a site on a subdomain (www.website.com/foobar) which pulls the default page view. Due to the nature of MVC apps, this default page view can also be reached through the "controller/action" URL of the default content (www.website.com/foobar/{controller}) and (www.website.com/foobar/{controller}/{action}).

For the sake of analytics and tracking, I would like any of these other URLs, besides the original short (www.website.com/foobar), to redirect back to this shorter URL.

So...
www.website.com/foobar/{controller}, when typed in, or clicked on in a bookmarked link, should redirect to www.website.com/foobar

I've tried playing around with the routing, but couldn't get anything to actually change the URL itself. I'm not sure if it's possible to change through mapping.

Edit: Has anyone used the HTTP Redirect within IIS7? I can redirect from the top tier, but cannot seem to get the redirect to work on any of the Views.

Comment: Are you having RESTful urls?

Comment: It's a very small application with only two or three views, and never uses any GET or POST URL's, but does use a post method in the Controller, if that's what you're referring to. I'm not 100% familiar with what constitutes a RESTful url.

Comment: So, foobar here in your question refers to the controller action ..right?

Comment: I'll use real terms to help. www.website.com/Quick-Quote is our subdomain that hosts this application. www.website.com/Quick-Quote/Quote/Index displays the default view, so this long url displays the same content as www.website.com/Quick-Quote. I'd like the long url to redirect back to the short one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem in IIS 7 by using the HTTP Redirect module. Because it's an MVC application it was a little trickier to setup a redirect on a view, but it's possible. I used this tutorial: [Creating a redirect in IIS7](http://ajrawson.com/creating-a-redirect-in-iis7)

Edit: While the above solution works, it tended to be unpredictable. I ended up solving it by reading the URL the user was inputting in the Index action of the Quote controller, and then redirecting if keywords I was looking for were in the URL. Just a simple if statement at the beginning of the Index action.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use routing alone to redirect up a domain.  I had a similar issue and after a few days of searching and asking around, I ended up using Redirect itself to get over the issue.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that. I'd upvote you but I don't have a high enough reputation yet!